# Kivy with cv2 in python (Read barcode)

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd, opencv

i try to make app for read barcode using android machine and i have problem i cant compare between cv and kivy  please if someone can help me .

code that read barcode from android camera using kivy

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.camera import Camera
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
import numpy as np
import cv2
from kivy.properties import ListProperty


class MainApp(App):
    
    def build(self):
        
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        cam = Camera(play=True, resolution=(640, 480))
        #cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        success, frame=self.read()
        for code in decode(frame):
            print(code.type)
            print(code.data.decode('utf-8'))

            cv2.imshow("Results", frame);
            cv2.waitKey(1);
 
       
        return cam

if __name__== "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

Comment: never ever mix GUIs from different libraries.

Answer (score -1):

what do you mean by " i cant compare between cv and kivy" ? I have working machine learning app in kivy using cam. So what do you exactly need ? You need o display img in cv window, or you want to display camera frames in kivy ? You can update the kivy window every x second:

```py
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super().__init__()
        self.capture = None

    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        super().__init__()
        self.capture = cv.VideoCapture(0)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / 30)  # update 30 fps

    def on_leave(self, *args):
        self.capture.release()
```

And then you can display frame as kivy image texture like this:

```py
    def update(self, dt):
        ret, frame = self.capture.read()

        if ret:
            buf1 = cv.flip(frame, 0)
            buf = buf1.tobytes()
            image_texture = Texture.create(
                size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')
            image_texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')
            self.ids['image'].texture = image_texture
```

And Image you can define in kivy:

```
MDBoxLayout:
    size_hint: .65,1
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Image: #webcam
        id: image
```

Comment: i want to display camera in kivy and the camera extract and read the barcode ofrom any thingany

Comment: If you need display camera in kivy and then work with the results in any other library you can use code above. Im using it in my face recognition kivy app